# Cascading Dropdowns from MSsql not cascading

Tags: alpha-five

Hia guys,

I'm trying to set up some cascading dropdowns to filter data within AlphaFive V11

I have an SQL table filled with the different categories, and with no cascading: the drop downs populate with all the data as expected (category, group, subgroup)

When I tick the "Cascading" and set a parent, however, the drop downs fail to populate, and in fact, the "Display value for no choices found" text doesn't show either.

When looking in Chrome's console, when I select an Item from the first (non-cascading dropdown) the following error shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined a5.js:8450
```

What's odd is I've tried a previously working component into the page, which gives the same error on that page, but works in the place it was originally developed.

Any ideas on how I can make these things work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - and a workaround for those who may follow!

Alpha attempts to load it's own jQuery, and jQuery UI when ajax drop downs are used.
To overcome the conflict: load jQuery from google rather inbuilt, thus forcing it to load in no-conflict mode.

Then hand written jQuery needs the $ signs replacing with jQuery.